# How to test throwing error from module root (not method)

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

We have module within there is some initial logic which test that some value was configured, if not, it throws error.. then also the module provides methods. I want to describe this in specification (test), using Jest framework and test the feature. Here is simplified reproduced example:

```js
// dependency.service.ts
export const something = {
    method() {
        return "methodValue";
    }
};

export default function somethingElse() {
    return "somethingElseValue";
}
```

```js
// index.ts 

import somethingElse, { something } from "./dependency.service";

const value1 = somethingElse();
const value2 = something.method();
console.log("ROOT somethingElse", value1);
console.log("ROOT something.method", value2);

// initialisation of module fails
if(value1 === 'throw_error' || value2 === 'throw_error') {
    throw 'Some error';
}

export function smElse() {
    const value = somethingElse();
    console.log("somethingElse", value);
    return value;
}

export function smMethod() {
    const value = something.method();
    console.log("somethingElse", value);
    return value;
}
```

```js
// index.spec.ts

import { smElse, smMethod } from './index';

jest.mock('./dependency.service', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn(() => 'MOCKED_somethingElseValue'),
    something: {
        method: jest.fn(() => 'MOCKED_methodValue'),
    },
}));

describe('index', () => {
    // some tests for happy paths

    it('smElse returns mocked value', () => {
        expect(smElse()).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`"MOCKED_somethingElseValue"`);
    });

    it('smMethod returns mocked value', () => {
        expect(smMethod()).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`"MOCKED_methodValue"`);
    });

    it('smElse returns per test mocked value', () => {
        const somethingElseMocked = require('./dependency.service').default;
        somethingElseMocked.mockReturnValueOnce('ANOTHER_MOCKED_somethingElseValue');
        expect(smElse()).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`"ANOTHER_MOCKED_somethingElseValue"`);
    });

    it('smMethod returns per test mocked value', () => {
        const something = require('./dependency.service').something;
        something.method.mockReturnValueOnce('ANOTHER_MOCKED_methodValue');
        expect(smMethod()).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`"ANOTHER_MOCKED_methodValue"`);
    });

    // this is testing the throwing error in module root 

    it('throws error when somethingElse returns specific message', () => {
        expect.assertions(1);
        
        jest.isolateModules(() => {
            const somethingElseMocked = require('./dependency.service').default;
            somethingElseMocked.mockReturnValueOnce('throw_error');

            try { 
                require('./index');
            } catch (error) {
                expect(error).toBe("Some error");
            }
        });
    });

    it('throws error when something.method returns specific message', () => {
        expect.assertions(1);
        
        jest.isolateModules(() => {
            const somethingMethodMocked = require('./dependency.service').something.method;
            somethingMethodMocked.mockReturnValueOnce('throw_error');

            try { 
                require('./index');
            } catch (error) {
                expect(error).toBe("Some error");
            }
        });
        
    });
});
```

"Try catch in isolation" solution does not work with async code as isolateModules method does not support async functions yet, reference: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10428. I need alternative solution which would support async code.

Whole reproduced example repo here: https://github.com/luckylooke/jestTestModuleRootThrow/tree/main

EDIT:
I found out that some asynchronicity is supported by isolateModules, at least my use case, once I used expect.assertions(1) following test works as expected:

```js
        it('throws error when token data are not valid', async () => {
            expect.assertions(1);
            jest.isolateModules(async () => {
                require('crypto-package').someMethod.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve({
                    decoderMethod: () => Promise.resolve('{ broken data }'),
                }));

                const { getTokenData } = require("./decoder.service");

                await expect(getTokenData('34534xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx12628')).rejects.toMatchInlineSnapshot(`"Invalid token data"`);
            });
        });
```

Comment: FYI rather than have a fake assertion you expect to fail if reached, you can use https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectassertionsnumber. Or use https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror instead of try and catch.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I cannot use `toThrow` method as it does not work with root errors.. it only works for methods throwing errors ‍♂️ But 'force fail test' can be replaced by assertion number, so a bit nicer, edited question, thanks 

Comment: You _can_ use `toThrow`, at least in your current implementation, because `require('./index')` **is** a method throwing an error. You'd probably be better off entirely refactoring this into something that doesn't need this test, e.g. extracting the logic that throws on import to a module exposing a function, which is _much_ easier to test, then having a thin wrapper that just calls that function on import.

Comment: Refactoring try/catch to `expect(require('./index')).toThrow()` is not catching error thrown in root of the module as I wrote before, try it yourself.. test always fails to execute. I would have to put that logic into separate method e.g.`init()` and call it immediately, then this `expect(require('./index').init()).toThrow()` works. But I don't want degrade readability of module to increase testability if not needed. Current solution with try/catch in test works, so it is good enough even I don't like it and I would prefer `toThrow` to be working as you suggest.

Comment: Of course that doesn't catch the error, it gets thrown in trying to resolve the value to pass to expect so expect never gets called. Read the examples and tips in the docs.